# How to have a grid have the minimum width so its elements get equal sizes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

When specifying the size of elements within a Grid with stars (ex `ColumnDefinitions="1*,2*"`), their sizes will follow the specified split (1/3 and 2/3, here) so long as there is enough space for that.

If space runs short due to the parent Grid constraints, then not cropping elements take priority.

For instance, the following XAML

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto">

  <Grid RowDefinitions="1*,1*" ColumnDefinitions="1*,1*" Grid.Column="0">
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="foo"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="baaaaaar"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

yields the following:

[image: min sizes items]

because the Grid size is constrained to its minimum by the parent Grid's Auto column definition.

I would like to specify that I want the child Grid to be constrained to the minimum size that lets it split the space according to the star definitions, without cropping. So, in my exemple, that would be:

[image: buttons have equal size]

What's the simplest (as defined in the UI as possible) way to accomplish this ?

Comment: `<UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="2">`

Comment: Note that setting both Rows and Colums of a UniformGrid is redundant. It is suffucient to set either the one or the other.